# How to do this fetch request?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm writing an app using Core Data where I've got two entities, one called Item and one called CustomLabel. One item can have many custom labels while each custom label can only be associated with one item.

Essentially, I'd like to go out and grab all the CustomLabels associated with one particular item so I can display them. How would I go about doing that?

(My CustomLabel entity has attributes LabelName and Value, and Item has attributes Name, Price, and Quantity.)

Comment: If you already have the `Item` then you can access the `CustomLabel` directly from the relationship with no need for a fetch. But presumably you're not interested in that? That is, assuming you've set up a Core Data relationship between them?

Comment: Wow. I had completely blanked on that. Fixed my problem completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
 NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", itemName];
 [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
 NSArray *customLabels = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
```

This assumes that you have Managed Object Context set up, Entities set up with relationships etc.

The entities you would have will be Item and CustomLabel. And you will create attributes for them and set up relationships between them.